# Want to insert one table's last inserted id into another table in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel-5.3

Want to insert the latest inserted one table's id into another table.

Suppose there are two tables `transactions` and `user_transactions`. Now I want to store data in `transaction` table and also want to store the last inserted `transactions` table `id` into another table `user_transactions`. Do all part in one function.

Here is my `store` function code where I want to do the above job.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new transaction;
    $data->title_id = $request->title_id;
    $data->transaction_type_id = '2';
    $data->amount = $request->amount;
    $data->save();

    $data_of_user_transaction = new user_transaction;
    $data_of_user_transaction->transaction_id = $data->id;
    $data_of_user_transaction->user_id = session('user_info.id');
    $data_of_user_transaction->save();
}
```

After did the code data is inserted in `transactions` table but not inserted in `user_transactions` table.

Answer (score 0):

I have got my answer . 
I didn't use `user_transaction` model at the top of my code.

Just add the below line at the top of my code.

```
use App\user_transaction;
```

Given `store function code` is totally okay.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this i have Auction Table and Rule table I want Auction to save both tables in same time but I want to store Auction_id in Rule Table Column so i did this and get an appropriate answer...

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
{
    $auction = new Auction();
    $auction->products_id= $id;
    $auction->auc_price=$request->input('price');
    $auction->r_price=$request->input('rprice');
    $auction->from=$request->input('date');
    $auction->to=$request->input('todate');
    $auction->auc_status= 1;
    $auction->save();
    $rules= new Rule();

    $rules->auction_id = $auction->id;
    $rules->from=$request->input('from');
    $rules->to=$request->input('to');
    $rules->gap=$request->input('gap');

    $rules->save();

  return back();


}
```